# Which is standard scaling of Android TextView sp or dip

Tags: android

Hi Iam developing android Titlebar , so I need to clarify which is use to android text either sp or dip

or

Which is standard and what is the difference between sp and dip? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android.

Answer (score 2):

SP is always used for textSize
DP is used for pretty much everything else

See "[Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)" for more info.

---

From the docs:

> One common pitfall you must avoid when designing your layouts is using absolute pixels to define distances or sizes. Defining layout dimensions with pixels is a problem because different screens have different pixel densities, so the same number of pixels may correspond to different physical sizes on different devices. Therefore, when specifying dimensions, always use either dp or sp units. A dp is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).

Answer (score 0):

sp is used for text size and dp for everything else. These are mainly  to achieve the best support for multiple screens with different sizes and density